# Woocommerce add_to_cart() then wp_safe_redirect() fails

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

A user clicks a link to select the type of product they want so I do some work to compute the products to add using code like this:

WC()->cart->add_to_cart( 6842,1 );

then i try to go directly to checkout:

wp_safe_redirect( wc_get_checkout_url() );

But it does not add the product to the cart.  But if I skip the redirect it works, but doesn't go where I want.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the cart contents before redirect

```
WC()->session->save_data();
```